# Pthreads in C++

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, pthreads

I'm practicing a c++ code on pthreads and there is some code I'm struggling to understand, I'm hoping someone here can give me some help with code explanation. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
01.#include <pthread.h>
02.#include <iostream>
03.#define SIZE 10
04.using namespace std;
05.int array[SIZE];

06.void *countNegativeNumbers(void *arg){...}  //Assuming this function works properly
07.void *calAverageNumber(void *arg){...}      //Assuming this function works properly
08.void *printReverseOrder(void *arg){...}     //Assuming this function works properly

09.int main(){
10.  pthread_t id,t1,t2,t3; //add pthreads and declare it here
11.  int creatT; //declare the int variable for creat thread later
12.  for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
13.    cin>>array[i];}
14.  creatT=pthread_create(&t1, NULL, countNegativeNumbers, NULL);
15.  if(creatT){
16.    cout << "ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is " << creatT << endl;
17.    return -1;}
18.  sleep(5); // busy wait.
19.  // same as line 14 to 18 creat threads for t2,t3 and do if statement and busy wait.
20.  creatT = pthread_join(t1, &status);
21.  if(creatT){
22.    cout<<" ERROR; failed to join "<<creatT<<endl;}
23.  // same as line 20 to 22 terminate t2 and t3 here.
24.  pthread_exit(0);
25. }
```

Question:

1. For lines 11-12, it uses a for loop to collect users' key in values, do we have any other options to do it? I cant use cin>>array[i]; since i is not declare here right?
2. Could anyone give me a detailed explanation for code lines 15 to 17? Do I really need those codes here? I think this is some kind of check if the thread is here or not?
3. For lines 20 to 22, pthread_join(thread, pointer) since int main has no pointer why I could not use NULL here?
4. line 24 pthread_exit(0); what is the 0 stand for?

Thanks for any helps here!

Comment: Forgetv about pthreads and use c++ threads. A lot of thought has gone into c++ threads to make them work nicely with c++, waste to not use them.

Answer (score 0):

1 - declare the arraywith definite size at line 5 , u also can use any method for getting input but this here are working fine

2 - if u look at manual of pthread create return value section , u will see that it return zero on success and error number otherwise, here is link for ref
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html

3- has same return value as pthread_create also for ref
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html

4- it terminate the thread and release all the  resources it was locked by it
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html

i also recommend using manual in future it will help u have better understanding of the code

Answer (score 0):

> For lines 11-12, it uses a for loop to collect users' key in values,
> do we have any other options to do it? I cant use cin>>array[i]; since
> i is not declare here right?

I don't see anything wrong with that. `i` is defined in `for(int i=0; i<10;i++){`, so it is valid inside the loop.

> Could anyone give me a detailed explanation for code lines 15 to 17?
> Do I really need those codes here? I think this is some kind of check
> if the thread is here or not?

Those lines are checking the return value of `pthread_create()`, to make sure the thread was actually created. See the [`pthread_create()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) manual.

> For lines 20 to 22, pthread_join(thread, pointer) since int main has
> no pointer why I could not use NULL here?

[`pthread_join()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) is used to join with the created thread and get its return value once it exits. The pointer argument could be `NULL` if you don't care about the return value.

> line 24 pthread_exit(0); what is the 0 stand for?

The return value. In this case, it is terminating the main thread and returning `0`. see [`pthread_exit()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html).